# (Ahlfors, p198) Why is it clear we can write $G(z-1)=ze^{\gamma(z)}G(z)$ when deriving the Gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

In Complex Analysis by Ahlfors (p198), the author starts with the functional
$$
G(z) = \prod_1^\infty \left( 1 + \frac{z}{n} \right) e^{-z/n}
$$
and goes on to state that we may obviously write 
$$
G(z-1)=ze^{\gamma(z)}G(z)
$$
where $\gamma(z)$ is entire. I fail to see how he comes up with this construction, other than that it provides a zero at $z=0$. How did he come up with this form?

He goes on to show that $\gamma$ is constant and equal to Euler's constant, 0.57722.

Comment: The quotient $G(z-1)/(zG(z))$ is an entire function that never vanishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is an entire function with zeros exactly at $z=-1, -2, -3, \dotsc$,
and all zeros are simple. It follows that (as already mentioned in
a comment) 
$$
  \frac{G(z-1)}{zG(z)}
$$
is an entire function without zeros, and therefore equal to $e^{\gamma(z)}$
for some entire function $\gamma$.